# Chef git sync using knife role create and new workstation setup

Tags: git, chef-infra

I have a simple question about keeping my chef-repo in sync with what's on the server.

Here is the steps I took to create a new role:

```
cd /chef-repo/roles
knife role create windows_base
```

Then when I do:

```
knife role list
```

I can see the new windows_base role appearing, however I do not see a json file created under roles. When I push this to git this file wont exist?

So when I go onto a different workstation and pull everything to that workstation, the role windows_base wont exist. Why is there no json file created when I do knife role create windows_base and there obviously is when creating a role manually using a .rb file.

Simply put - how can I keep my chef-repo in sync with git if there is no file created and the role is directly created on the server?

Comment: Also ~immediately posted to Discourse https://discourse.chef.io/t/chef-git-sync-using-knife-role-create-and-new-workstation-setup/9630/1. Please don't do that.

Comment: hi @coderanger I would usually copy the answer across if one has been answered immediately. Reason I also posted on discourse is because I didnt know it existed. :)

Comment: Basically the same support volunteers watch both places, so you can usually just pick one or the other. Discourse is mildly better for super niche questions, but this is just a general query.

Comment: @coderanger apologies I didnt know about discourse. Every day is a school day :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `knife * create` commands are issuing the create directly against the API. We don't offer generator commands (which live under `chef generate`) for roles, you'll just have to create the file yourself. In general you probably don't want to use the `create` commands, instead make the files you want and then `knife upload roles/`.